# AndroidManifest.xml structured incorrectly

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, simulator

### UPDATED OCT 22 2021

- My debug **AndroidManifest.xml** file is giving me errors at build time.
- Happens only with Android Simulator, IOS runs perfectly.
- android.useAndroidX=true
- android.enableJetifier=true

**SUMMARY**:
The error is being caused by the  tag:
**com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity** which is out of place. Even if I move it to the right place, it automatically moves back when building.

Error I am getting:

```
error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
```

Here is my debug/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tomasward.fredi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- 适配Android R包可见性 开始 -->
    <queries package="com.tomasward.fredi" >
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <!-- For browser content -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent> <!-- End of browser content -->
        <!-- For CustomTabsService -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Fredi"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.tomasward.fredi.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

           
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyD9pKRFa-bPpig6wnQC5kj7nNMFF72rN3U" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-2176711646772763~2658546918"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-2176711646772763~2658546918" />
            <!--
                 Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="cct.com.tomasward.fredi"
                    android:scheme="fbconnect" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Set up the Sign in with Apple activity, such that it's callable from the browser-redirect -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithAppleCallback"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="signinwithapple" />
                <data android:path="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tomasward.fredi.flutter.image_provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/flutter_image_picker_file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedded_views_preview"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
        
        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tomasward.fredi.FacebookInitProvider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="genericidp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="recaptcha" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tomasward.fredi.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />
        <provider
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tomasward.fredi.luckProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureSelectorActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureSelectorWeChatStyleActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureSelectorCameraEmptyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Picture.Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureCustomCameraActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PicturePreviewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureSelectorPreviewWeChatStyleActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureVideoPlayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PictureExternalPreviewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.luck.picture.lib.PicturePlayAudioActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.PictureMultiCuttingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
       
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tomasward.fredi.mobileadsinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="com.tomasward.fredi.workmanager-init"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:exported="false"
            android:multiprocess="true" />

        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.SystemAlarmService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_job_service_default"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable$BroadcastReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$BatteryChargingProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$BatteryNotLowProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$StorageNotLowProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$NetworkStateProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxyUpdateReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.UpdateProxies" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.room.MultiInstanceInvalidationService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As requested, here is the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java code:

```
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
    try {
      dev.gilder.tom.apple_sign_in.AppleSignInPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("dev.gilder.tom.apple_sign_in.AppleSignInPlugin"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin apple_sign_in, dev.gilder.tom.apple_sign_in.AppleSignInPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_auth, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_core, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabasePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_database, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabasePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_storage, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new ru.innim.flutter_login_facebook.FlutterLoginFacebookPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_login_facebook, ru.innim.flutter_login_facebook.FlutterLoginFacebookPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle, io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      com.roughike.fluttertwitterlogin.fluttertwitterlogin.TwitterLoginPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.roughike.fluttertwitterlogin.fluttertwitterlogin.TwitterLoginPlugin"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_twitter_login, com.roughike.fluttertwitterlogin.fluttertwitterlogin.TwitterLoginPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutter.plugins.vibrate.VibratePlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("flutter.plugins.vibrate.VibratePlugin"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_vibrate, flutter.plugins.vibrate.VibratePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin google_mobile_ads, io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin google_sign_in, io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.ggichure.github.hexcolor.HexcolorPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin hexcolor, com.ggichure.github.hexcolor.HexcolorPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin image_cropper, vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin image_picker, io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.chavesgu.images_picker.ImagesPickerPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin images_picker, com.chavesgu.images_picker.ImagesPickerPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      com.github.adee42.keyboardvisibility.KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.github.adee42.keyboardvisibility.KeyboardVisibilityPlugin"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin keyboard_visibility, com.github.adee42.keyboardvisibility.KeyboardVisibilityPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin path_provider, io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin shared_preferences, io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin sqflite, com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the java code also.

Comment: done @JustInCoding, that was the java file I could find.

Comment: @TomasWard
Below `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, you have an `<activity ...>` tag. Please move that one inside the `<application ...>` tag. NOTE: You have an existing `UCropActivity` inside the `<application ...>` tag

Comment: @rickimaru if I try to move or delete that activity tag, and build the app, it automatically moves  or regenerates outside of the application tag.  The second UCropActivity tag also regenerates automatically even if I delete it.

Comment: @TomasWard May I also know why you're adding it in the `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` not in `main/AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @rickimaru here is my main Android Manifest: https://pastebin.com/yhNmpKWD. I am using the debug one because the error pointed to that file. Here is the error: `ERROR:C:\Users\xxx\StudioProjects\xxx\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.`

Comment: I noticed that `tools:replace="android:theme"` might be causing the duplication and error. Yet if I don't add that line in the main manifest, **this error appears**:  `Attribute activity#com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity@theme value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:76:12-68
   is also present at [com.github.LuckSiege.PictureSelector:picture_library:v2.6.1] AndroidManifest.xml:66:13-58 value=(@style/Base.Theme.NoActionBar).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.`

Comment: So that it is clear: I am not adding any activity tags in the debug file, those are being added automatically if I insert `tools:replace="android:theme"` in my main file under the activity tag of UCropActivity.

Comment: @TomasWard I'm just confused on your `Debug` manifest. There are so many duplicates comparing to `Main` manifest. `Debug` manifest extends the `Main` manifest so I'm not sure why you have duplicate tags. If you want these activities to be present in all build types (release, profile, debug), you should put it in `Main` manifest.

Comment: @rickimaru that might just be the problem. **This project has been recently migrated from a mac** and downloaded from git hub. It is the first time I try running on `android` but I am getting these errors. Any way to clean these files/project to remove duplicates? I have never touched the debug manifest file, that's why its weird.

Comment: @TomasWard Ohhh... Yeah, can you try removing duplicates in `Debug`. All of that could be in `Main` and only special permissions or others are in `Debug`.

Comment: @rickimaru could you post the above comment as an answer so I can give you the bounty? This was what most helped me.

Comment: @TomasWard Answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Actual answer

In a flutter project there are three main Android Manifest Files. It seems that when I wanted to set up Google Ad Mob package I accidentally inserted

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

in debug/AndroidManifest.xml, when it needed to go in **main/AndroidManifest.xml**. This was causing duplications and errors. After cleaning and building the error is gone, yet I still can't run the app due to incorrect setup of google ad mob package.

Bottom line: When using `google_mobile_ads` package, set it up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just confused on your `Debug` manifest. There are so many duplicates comparing to `Main` manifest. `Debug` manifest extends the `Main` manifest so I'm not sure why you have duplicate tags. If you want these activities to be present in all build types (release, profile, debug), you should put it in `Main` manifest.

Try removing duplicates in `Debug`. All of that could be in `Main` and only special permissions or others are in `Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `you need to migrate your android project to v2 embedding` (quoted from https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper). So could you please try this?

Secondly, could you please search in your code where you use `com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity`? I guess it may be caused by some kind of build script, which automatically injects that section of code into your xml (but inject wrongly).

Thirdly, maybe also show all your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have 2 `activity` tags with the name `com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity`.

Move

```xml
 <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

into the `application` tag.

Remove,

```xml
<activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.NoActionBar" />
```